# "Cannot change resolution strategy of dependency configuration" Error on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to build an application that is using Android-appauth module and I am getting the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':appauth'.
> Cannot change resolution strategy of dependency configuration ':appauth:mdDoclet' after it has been resolved.
```

After doing some searching on the internet I am not able to figure out what this error is indicating.
Please let me know what I need to do in order to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: You might get your solution from here: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out, had to change my dependencies to later gradle version:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'. // previous 4.0.0`